# Как в IIS настроить загрузку index.html для SPA, если маршрут не существует?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Мне нужно выдавать данные фронтенда и отдельно api, но если ссылка не найдена- выдавать index.html.

Фактические есть api, файловая система с js,css, html файлами и картинками,
и на любой другой url выдавать index.html.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: может urlrewrite поможет: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/24.2.php

Comment: @Konst - а при этом не будет смены самого url?
мне нужно, что б по запросу - site.com/abracadabra/notfound-url/1234 выдало index.html и фактически бекенд вообще ничего не знает об этом маршруте - его потом фронтенд распакует.
что б урл не сменился на /index.html

Comment: может тогда просто кастомную 404 страницу сделать

Comment: @Konst а без 404 страницы как делают spa -что б всё отдать фронтенду и пусть он сам разбирается?

Comment: если вопрос про проектированию spa, то наверное проще почитать про  использование Vue/React/Angular